# ifelse and replacing a single value

Tags: r

As training, I'm trying to reproduce a data transformation on this db ( https://studysites.uk.sagepub.com/dsur/study/DSUR%20Data%20Files/Chapter%205/DownloadFestival(No%20Outlier).dat )

```
dlf$day2<-as.numeric(dlf$day2)


dlf$recday2b<- 1/(dlf$day2 + 1)
dlf$recday2b[is.na(dlf$recday2b)] <-0
```

using `ifelse`, but I'm unable to make `ifelse` replace NA values with 0s.

I tried these without success:

```
dlf$recday2b<-ifelse(is.na(dlf$day2), replace(dlf$day2, NA, 0), 1/(dlf$day2 + 1))
```

```
dlf$recday2b<-ifelse(dlf$day2!="", 1/(dlf$day2 + 1), dlf$day2==0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you don't have a problem to create the new variable `recday2b` but you just want to change when the recday2b is NA to 0

Using ifelse you could try

```
dlf$recday2b <-ifelse(is.na(dlf$recday2b), 0, dlf$recday2b) 
dlf$recday2b <- ifelse(is.na(dlf$day2), 0, dlf$recday2b) #same result
```

Otherwise you also have the `replace_na()` function that takes a dataframe or vector as an argument

Comment: It was just "0"!! Thanks! I was overcomplicating my life by assuming that ifelse required a function

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like this with `replace_na` using the argument `replace = list("variable_name" = 0)`, like so:

```r
library(tidyverse)
dlf <- tribble(~A, ~recday2b, 
        1, NA,
        2, 0.5, 
        1, 0.2, 
        3, NA); dlf
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>       A recday2b
#>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     1     NA  
#> 2     2      0.5
#> 3     1      0.2
#> 4     3     NA

dlf %>% 
  replace_na(replace = list("recday2b" = 0))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>       A recday2b
#>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     1      0  
#> 2     2      0.5
#> 3     1      0.2
#> 4     3      0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>